# Mapping CentOS NFS to another CentOS Server

Tags: centos, mount, nfs, centos5

CentOS 5.5

I have a web application running on a server and it needs access to another CentOS server's file system running in the same network (via private IP).  After doing a bunch of googling it looks like mounting the drive via NFS is a good way to go, but I'm not finding any good step by step instructions on how to go about it.  I've read the man docs on the mount command and read some docs on the CentOS wiki as well but I feel like I'm missing something.  Here is what I'm trying

```
mount -t nfs my.ip.address:/somePath /somePath/mount
```

I keep getting a 'no route to host' error but I can ping the server just fine. I'm guessing that I am possibly missing a port I need to open or something, but again, can't find information that makes sense to a non-sysadmin like myself.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across this, followed it step by step, and now I'm up and running!

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-rhel-nfs-v4-configuration/